# Who is Matrona which asked Reb Yossi many questions?

Tags: history, women, midrash, parashat-toldot

The Medrash in last week Parsha says מטרונא שאלה את רבי יוסי בן חלפתא אמרה ליה למה יצא עשו תחלה if we search for Reb Yossi with maternya there are a number of questions which she asked. Jastrow says it is a female, do we know who she was? Is she the wife of Reb Yossi? If she is so important why not call her by name?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HeArukh%2C_Letter_Mem.173?vhe=Sefer_HeArukh,_Lublin_1883&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I know that in Avot D’Rabbi Natan Perek 16, they tell the story of Rabbi Tzadok who was taken captive and enslaved by a מטרוניתא (translated as matron) and they tell a whole story of how Rabbi tzaddok refused to have relations with a girl that was right in front of him. The story withstanding, matronita here is just some random goy mistress, so maybe in your case as well

Comment: Rabbi Yose is an aggadist and many of his teachings follow the format of his answering a Roman Matron. As far as I know, she is never identified by name or given any additional information, nor are we given any proof that she was real and not just a literary device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer:

The term "Matrona" or "Matronita" usually refers to a high-class woman<sup>1</sup> (compare the modern English word "matron") (see again [Jastrow](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Jastrow%2C_%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%98%D6%B0%D7%A8%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%A0%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%AA.1?ven=London,_Luzac,_1903&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) fully and [Dr. Henry Abramson](https://outorah.org/p/64797/)), and you'll [find](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%90&tab=text&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) many stories where various rabbis meet up with such matroniyot. The word Matrona is Latin in origin.

Dr. Abramson in the above link noted that several modern scholars think the matronita is a literary device and none or most of these women didn't actually exist. That would serve to explain why they are unnamed. However, he also brings a view by Judith Baskin who suggested that not only these women may have been real, but they may have also been high-class Jewish women. With that said, it seems to me that even if that's the case, these women were not the wives of the rabbis, who are usually referred to as "bitehu/bitei" (ביתהו/ביתיה) (for example, Imma Shalom in [Bava Metzia 59b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.59b.10?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi)).

I would guess that in some cases the rabbis did not know the names of the women who spoke to them<sup>2</sup> and in other cases the sages who wrote the gemara did not know/remember the name. It seems that in general, it was not important to the stories to mention the women's names. With that said, keep in mind that comparatively few women are named in Chazalic texts. Not even all of the wives of rabbis that are mentioned are named (for example, [Shabbat 33b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.33b.6?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi)).

---

<sup>1</sup> Eliezer Margaliyot in his essay "[Hebrew and Aramaic in the Talmud and the Midrash](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24370449#metadata_info_tab_contents)", Leshonenu 27/28, p. 32 noted that the importance of these women is also exemplified by the fact that in many cases, their words are brought in Hebrew and not the lower-class Aramaic, as was the case with the minim (heretics), who often earned the mockery and scorn of Chazal.

<sup>2</sup> I imagine them, for example, going to discuss a certain subject with an important Roman or Jewish person and being stopped on the way out by that person's wife/sister/other female relative who happened to be there, or perhaps being randomly stopped by such a person in some public area.

Comment: Thank you!
That makes alot if sense!

Comment: @fulltimekollelguy you're welcome.

Comment: What exactly does the woman being used as a ”literary device” mean

Comment: @CuriousYid it means that the insertion of women into these stories was a technique to express a certain idea that the person/people who wrote the story wanted to express.